# values must be an object with value names as keys

Tags: node.js, express, graph, graphql

I have created an enum type for my object

```
const MonthType = new GraphQLEnumType({
      name: 'monthType',
      value: {
        JANUARY:{
          value: "January"
        }, 
        FEBRUARY: {
          value: 'February'
        }, 
        MARCH: {
          value: 'March'
        }, 
        MAY: {
          value: 'May'
        }, 
        JUNE: {
          value: 'June'
        }, 
        JULY: {
          value: 'July'
        }, 
        AUGUST: {
          value: "August"
        }, 
        SEPTEMBER: {
          value: 'September'
        }, 
        OCTOBER: {
          value: 'October'
        }, 
        NOVEMEBER: {
          value: 'November'
        }, 
        DECEMBER: {
          value: 'December'
        }
      }
    })
```

which I am using kind of like this in my Object type

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User', // Importance of Name here
  fields: () => ({
    id: {
      type: GraphQLInt
    },
    userId: {
      type: GraphQLInt
    },
    gradMonth: {
      type: MonthType
    },
```

Now, Whenever I start my express server, I am thrown the following error in my code

> monthType values must be an object with value names as keys

What I intend to do? I want the user to select, pass the value of the month which should be one of these.

Can someone help me in figuring out why I am getting the following error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `value` by `values` at the begining :

```
const MonthType = new GraphQLEnumType({
      name: 'monthType',
      values: { // <=== here
      //...
```